# How can I pass $post object to 'save_post' add_action?

Tags: posts, editor, save-post

I have several functions that are called from inside a [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) function. However, all of the functions that use the `$post` object are returning incorrect values because it appears that the default value being passed to [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) is the post ID rather than the post object.

How can I pass the post object to the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) function in addition to the post ID?

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_function');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_function', 10, 2);
```

And the `$post object` will be passed as second argument to your function:

```
function my_save_function($post_ID, $post) {
```

Comment: @sorich: I'm getting an different (and incorrect) value for $post->ID echo inside the "my_save_function" than when its echo'd outside that function. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `echo $post_ID` and `echo $post->ID` return different results?

Comment: Every time I test, the value of $post_ID, it gets incremented by one. Its as if this were a draft version ID incrementing. Any ideas?

Comment: $post_ID and $post->ID are the same. However, the value being returned is in the 300's (increments by one each time i click "Publish" to test). My post id should be 176

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it has something to do with the post revision. Are the values of `$post->post_content` and `$post->post_title` correct?

Comment: Never use the $post parameter. WP stores and sends a different copy in the cache, meaning it could be stale by the time your function gets called.

Comment: @ScottB you're seeing it used both for the post and it's revision. Since revisions were introduced you need to get the post, and check it's type to make sure you're dealing with the one you're looking for.

Comment: OK, I think both point to the same content object, though the IDs themselves are different. My core problem though, is I'm getting different values returned from my functions when they are called from the save_post function than when they are called on page load. Its got me stumped...

Comment: @Denis, the `$post` object passed to `do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);` is actually the results of a `$post = get_post($post_ID);`. How can it be staled?

Comment: For example, I have a function that returns the keyword density of the post content. When called on page load it returns accurate value of 2.5%, but when called from within the save_post function it returns 100%, which is why I'm tracking back to the postID. Why would the function return different values depending on where its called from?

Comment: @Scott B, you can submit you code in another question and we will help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @sorich87: in the filtering part of wp, the same object gets passed over and over. By contrast, wp_cache_get() returns a clone of the freshest version on each call - which is then returned by get_post(). When using the $post argument, you're really working on a copy of the post as saved but before any plugin messes around with it.

Comment: Here is the question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/function-returns-different-value-when-called-from-save-post-than-when-called-on

Comment: @Denis, I think I get it: $post does not contain the modifications done by all the other functions hooking in to 'save_post', right?

Comment: @sorich: exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Denis! I always thought that $post was the latest version depending on the priority order.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_post($post_id)`

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post