# Function returns different value when called from 'save_post' than when called on page load

Tags: functions

The "word_count" function below returns different values depending on where its called from. Why?

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_save', 10, 2);

function myPlugin($post)
{
    global $rockScore;
    global $text;
    $text = strip_tags($post->post_content);
    echo word_count($post); //returns "350"
}

function word_count($post)
{
    global $text;
    $word_count = explode(' ', $text);
    $word_count = count($word_count);
return $word_count;
}

function my_custom_save($postID, $post){
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $postID;
    }
    else
    {
        if($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($postID))
        {
        $postID = $parent_id;
        }
        echo word_count($post);die; //still returns "1"
    }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myPlugin');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably revisions. Check $post->post_type.

Comment: Bingo. Echo $post->post_type = "revision". What's the solution? How can I pass the original post object to the function?

Comment: You should check the post type when using the save_post action by adding 
  if(wp_is_post_autosave($post_id) || wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
   return $post_id;
  }

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've revised my question with the updated code, but I'm still getting an incorrect value from the function.

Comment: @Scott B: why don't you just pass the post_content to your word count function `word_count($post->post_content);` instead of using a `global $text`?

Comment: @sorich, that does work. I just figured it was too expensive to call it each time vs storing it in global.

Comment: Glad it works now. Does that code solve your previous question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-capture-word-count-from-the-post-object-inside-of-editor? If yes, you may want to post it there so that the question does not remain unsolved.

Comment: @sorich, I'm still left with the problem that $post->ID returns the revision ID rather than the original post's id.

Comment: Try using `$post = get_post($post_ID);` as @Denis previously pointed out.

Comment: That works. Thanks! I've still got problems with my other functions when called via this save hook, I'll post them later.